# what is the difference between core search and search api indexing

Tags: search

What is the difference between core search and search api indexing. The below screen shows up once i visit search setting and number of item left to index is 1809. (en/admin/config/search/settings)

[image]

But once i see the index of my search server created under search api it show different results . (en/admin/config/search/search_api/index/recipes_index)

[image]

I understand that core search is indexing all items in the site so does my Search API index?

Can someone please explain the difference ?

Thanks

Comment: Search api uses different tables to index content. If you're using search_api you should disable the core search module.

Comment: thanks @MariusIlie. But i am using core search to search for other content in the site and Search API only for only content type ( Recipes )? I have added filters for this in search api index. But still it show 1809 Items as total. May be its normal ?